# What's the command to spawn a blaze that HAS a name but is invisible and that will despawn after 10 seconds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What's the command to spawn a blaze that HAS a name but is invisible and that will despawn after 10 seconds?
I need it cause I'm making a haunted Dungeon.

Comment: What are you trying to use the blaze for? Just the sound effect? A floating nametag?

Comment: No as a mob. For a jumpscare.

Comment: It also needs to wear a skull from a player.

Comment: We at Arqade appreciate a little bit of effort from the players. What methods have you tried so far? Showing us that you've actually tried something first, before coming to us, definitely shows some effort.

Comment: @SCPMiner So let me make sure I'm getting this right. You want to cause a player jumpscare with an invisible Blaze? So, essentially just a floating head?

Comment: Mostly yes. Since i already have scary things in the background.

Comment: And Kaizerwolf ive tried to make a invisible blaze and skeleton but it doesnt work.

Comment: If you have *something*, you should be asking what's wrong with it and how to fix it, and not asking us to create an entire mechanism from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I can't always be 100% sure of things, but using another command-generator site a command for a invisible blaze with a player head of your choice would be like this:

```
/summon Blaze ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"PUTNAMEHERE",CustomNameVisible:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:PUTPLAYERNAMEHERE}}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],Invulnerable:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:200000,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

This command will ONLY work if it is in a command block.
 ALSO:
 I could not find a way to make it despawn in 10 seconds (I'm sorry,)
 It is also invulnerable, so the player playing the map cannot just punch the blaze.
 IN FULL CAPS in the command are things you will need to customize or change.
 Hopefully I could help...

Comment: Well, you could give it a wither effect and low health. Or just use a timer to remove the blaze after a set time.